# Breadcrumb control with XAML

Tags: wpf, user-interface, xaml, user-controls

I want to implement a breadcrumb control that looks like the following:

[image: example breadcrumb design]

It should match the following criteria:

- it should be easy to push and pop levels to the stack
- the current level should have an alternative style
- all parent levels should have a nice mouse over
- the width of each level should grow flexibly with it's content
- (Optional) on limited width, the content should apply text elide

Right now, I am using a horizontal StackPanel and just add styled buttons. But I don't see a straight forward way of achieving the overlapped design.

What would be your take on the XAML-structure and the XAML-controls to use?

Answer (score 2):

You cam implement a custom BreadCrumb extending from TabControl.

Check the [this link](http://www.wpfblogger.com/post/BreadCrumb-TabControl-Style-for-WPF-40.aspx).

Comment: Great! The link is just what I was looking for.

Comment: I took a quick look at the source, and I couldn't figure out, how to automatically distinguish the last (current) element.

Comment: The link is broken, any alternative source?

Answer (score 1):

An ItemsControl using a horizontal StackPanel as its ItemsPanel, and some styled buttons in the DataTemplate is what I'd use. Judicious use of negative margins should give you the overlapping effect.